# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin a_{n}}{\sqrt{n}+na_{n}}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_{n}>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is convergent.

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin a_{n}}{\sqrt{n}+na_{n}}$ convergent
>   ?

Since $\sin a_{n}$ is bounded by one,

and

> $\sqrt{n}\rightarrow\infty$
>   as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so $\frac{\sin a_{n}}{\sqrt{n}+na_{n}}\rightarrow0$.

I tried limit comparison test,

for instance $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$,
but did work. Any hint?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$$\vert b_n \vert= \vert \frac{\sin a_{n}}{\sqrt{n}+na_{n}} \vert \leq \vert \frac{\sin a_n}{\sqrt{n}} \vert \leq \vert \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}} \vert \leq \vert a_n \vert $$
where the first inequality is due to the fact that $a_n \geq 0$ and the second one is due to $\sin x < x $.

Now you can say by Comparison test that $\vert b_n \vert$ converges. Hence, $b_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Thanks @nosrati for the comment.

Comment: Is it valid If $\sin a_n<0$ ?

Comment: you are absolutely right @Nosrati .. sounds good now ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sin a_{n}}{\sqrt{n}+na_{n}}\le\frac{\sin a_{n}}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n} 
 a_{n}}\le\frac{\sin a_{n}}{\sqrt{n}\cdot (1+a_{n}) }\le\left|\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right| $$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}\sqrt{n}}{a_n\sqrt{n+1}}\le \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$$

as we know that $1+a_n\ge0$

Comment: This doesn't help. Since $\sum a_n < \infty$, $a_n/a_{n+1} > 1$ infinitely often.

Comment: now does that help

Comment: $\sum 1/\sqrt{n}$ doesn't converge. Your bound is too loose.

Comment: So a series less than a divergent series. What can u say about that @James ?

Comment: ok I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

$$
b_n = \frac{\sin a_n}{\sqrt{n} + n a_n} = \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\sin a_n}{a_n}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}a_n}
$$
 $|(\sin a_n)/a_n|\le 1$, and since the $a_n$ are all positive, $|1+\sqrt{n} a_n|^{-1} \le 1$. This means we have
$$
|b_n| \le \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}\le a_n
$$
for all $n$. Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, by the comparison test $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ also converges.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|\sin x| \le |x|$ for all $x,$ we have

$$\left|\frac{\sin a_n}{\sqrt n +na_n}\right |= \frac{|\sin a_n| }{\sqrt n +na_n} \le \frac{|a_n| }{\sqrt n +na_n}$$ $$ = \frac{a_n }{\sqrt n +na_n} \le a_n$$

for all $n.$ Because $\sum a_n < \infty,$ our series converges absolutely by the comparison test. Hence it converges.